# Should a Python generator raise an exception when there are no more elements to yield?

Tags: python

Should a Python generator raise an exception when there are no more elements to yield?

Which one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only time I know that you have to manually `raise StopIteration` is when you are implementing a `next()` method on a class to signal that the iterator is terminated.  For generators (functions with `yield` statements in them), the end of the function or a `return` statement will properly trigger the `StopIteration` for you.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't have to, but it can raise a [StopIteration](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration).

The more normal way to end the iteration is to let the function end and return naturally, or to use a return statement. This will cause a StopIteration to be raised on your behalf.

Comment: This answers my vague question, but I was wondering to know if in my code I should manually raise it.

Comment: You had no way of predicting this back in 2010, but for the future reader, this is not true anymore, following https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/. Now, raising a StopIteration in a generator will raise a RuntimeError.